# PHP AJAX RSS reader

Tags: php, ajax, rss

I've been using this PHP/AJAX rss reader http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp - it works well, but I have been trying to make more than three items come up in the resulting HTML. I've looked through all the PHP, but for the life of me I can't work out how to make the thing show more than three items.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PHP loop it says

```
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
```

Which basicly means, **i** equals 0, and as long as **i** is less than 2 keep looping, and in each loop add one.

So it goes `0 -> 1 -> 2`.... and stops

Just insert the number you want :)

Comment: is there a way to keep the loop, but allow any numbers higher as well?

Comment: Well you need to stop it sometime or it will eat the servers memory. Any thing specific you are trying to accomplish? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
```

it should work by increasing the 2 at that line inside the php code